# When to use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock vs. for

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ios4, objective-c-blocks

Besides the obvious differences:

- Use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` when you need both the index and the object
- <s>Don't use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` when you need to modify local variables</s> (I was wrong about this, see bbum's answer)

Is `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` generally considered better or worse when `for (id obj in myArray)` would also work? What are the advantages/disadvantages (for example is it more or less performant)?

Comment: I like to use it if I need the current index.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509662/objective-c-enumerateusingblock-vs-fast-enumeration

Answer (score 358, accepted):

Ultimately, use whichever pattern you want to use and comes more naturally in the context.

While `for(... in ...)` is quite convenient and syntactically brief, `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` has a number of features that may or may not prove interesting:

- `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` will be as fast or faster than fast enumeration (`for(... in ...)` uses the `NSFastEnumeration` support to implement enumeration).  Fast enumeration requires translation from an internal representation to the representation for fast enumeration.  There is overhead therein.  Block-based enumeration allows the collection class to enumerate contents as quickly as the fastest traversal of the native storage format.  Likely irrelevant for arrays, but it can be a huge difference for dictionaries.
- "Don't use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock when you need to modify local variables" - not true; you can declare your locals as `__block` and they'll be writable in the block.
- `enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:` supports either concurrent or reverse enumeration.
- with dictionaries, block based enumeration is the only way to retrieve the key and value simultaneously.

Personally, I use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` more often than `for (... in ...)`, but - again - personal choice.

Comment: Wow, very informative. I wish I could accept both of these answers, but I'm going with Chuck's because it resonates a bit more with me. Also, I found your blog (http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/08/29/blocks-tips-tricks/) while searching for __block and learned even more. Thank you.

Comment: Just for sheer informative value I'm giving this a vote. Nice answer.

Comment: For the record, block-based enumeration is not always "as fast or faster" http://www.mikeabdullah.net/slow-block-based-dictionary-enumeration.html

Comment: Nice find.  That is seemingly broken.   Please file a bug (and post the # here).  Note that it may be broken *now* for compatibility reasons, as an oversight, or as an implementation details and it will be fixed in some later release.

Comment: Someone posted it to the Objective-C mailing list at some point, prompting this reply: http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2012/Sep/msg00012.html

Comment: But aren't blocks executed in a secondary thread? which means the line of code after the enumeration will execute BEFORE the enuneration blocks ends?

Comment: @VanDuTran Blocks are only executed on a separate thread if you tell them to be executed on a separate thread.   Unless you use the concurrency option of enumeration, then it'll be executed on the same thread as the call was made

Comment: Why do you need __block for this? You won't get retain loop since you don't store block. Any else reason block shouldn't retain?

Comment: @desudesudesu If you need to modify a variable declared locally to the method's scope within a block contained in that method, you'll need to use `__block`.  Otherwise, the assignment will toss a compiler error.  Nothing to do with retain cycles.

Comment: Nick Lockwood did a really nice article on this, and it seems `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` is still significantly slower than fast enumeration for arrays and sets. I wonder why? http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/high-performance-collection-looping-objective-c.html

Comment: Although it's kind of an implementation detail, it should be mentioned in this answer among the differences between the two approaches that `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` wraps each invocation of the block with an autorelease pool (as of OS X 10.10 at least). This explains the performance difference compared to `for in` which doesn't do that.

Comment: One thing to add: block based enumeration gives you the (correct) object's index for free, while in fast enumeration it would require an rather expensive `indexOfObject:` call that isn't even returning the correct index for sure.

Comment: The claims of enumerateObjectsUsingBlock being "just as fast as" for-in are provably false. See my answer below... It's actually REALLY SLOW in comparison. If performance matters, don't use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock! In fact, don't use it _unless you have to_.

Answer (score 83):

For simple enumeration, simply using fast enumeration (i.e. a `for…in…` loop) is the more idiomatic option. The block method might be marginally faster, but that doesn't matter much in most cases — few programs are CPU-bound, and even then it's rare that the loop itself rather than the computation inside will be a bottleneck.

A simple loop also reads more clearly. Here's the boilerplate of the two versions:

```
for (id x in y){
}

[y enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id x, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
}];
```

Even if you add a variable to track the index, the simple loop is easier to read.

So when you should use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`? When you're storing a block to execute later or in multiple places. It's good for when you're actually using a block as a first-class function rather than an overwrought replacement for a loop body.

Comment: `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` will either be the same speed or faster than fast enumeration in all cases.  `for(... in ...)` uses fast enumeration which requires the collection to provide some interim representation of the internal data structures.  As you note, likely irrelevant.

Comment: +1 `When you're storing a block to execute later or in multiple places. It's good for when you're actually using a block as a first-class function rather than an overwrought replacement for a loop body.`

Comment: @bbum My own tests show that `enumerateObjects...` can actually be slower then fast enumeration with a loop.  I ran this test several thousand times; the body of the block and loop were the same single line of code: `[(NSOperation *)obj cancel];`.  The averages: fast enum loop - `-[JHStatusBar dequeueStatusMessage:] [Line: 147] Fast enumeration time (for..in..loop): 0.000009` and for the block -
`-[JHStatusBar dequeueStatusMessage:] [Line: 147] Enumeration time using block: 0.000043`.  Weird that the time difference is so large and consistent but, obviously, this is a very specific test case.

Answer (score 44):

Although this question is old, things have not changed, *the accepted answer is incorrect.*

The `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` API was not meant to supersede `for-in`, but for a totally different use case:

- It allows the application of arbitrary, non-local logic. i.e. you don’t need to know what the block does to use it on an array.
- Concurrent enumeration for large collections or heavy computation (using the `withOptions:` parameter)

### Fast Enumeration with `for-in` is still the *idiomatic* method of enumerating a collection.

Fast Enumeration benefits from brevity of code, readability and [additional optimizations](http://nshipster.com/enumerators/) which make it unnaturally fast. Faster than a old C for-loop!

A quick test concludes that in the year 2014 on iOS 7, `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` is consistently 700% slower than for-in (based on 1mm iterations of a 100 item array).

*Is performance a real practical concern here?*

Definitely not, with rare exception.

The point is to demonstrate that there is little benefit to using `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` over `for-in` without a really good reason. It doesn't make the code more readable... or faster... or thread-safe. (another common misconception).

The choice comes down to personal preference. For me, the idiomatic and readable option wins. In this case, that is Fast Enumeration using `for-in`.

### Benchmark:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    arr[i] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
}
int i;
__block NSUInteger length;

i = 1000 * 1000;
uint64_t a1 = mach_absolute_time();
while (--i > 0) {
    for (NSString *s in arr) {
        length = s.length;
    }
}
NSLog(@"For-in %llu", mach_absolute_time()-a1);

i = 1000 * 1000;
uint64_t b1 = mach_absolute_time();
while (--i > 0) {
    [arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *s, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        length = s.length;
    }];
}
NSLog(@"Enum %llu", mach_absolute_time()-b1);
```

**Results:**

```
2014-06-11 14:37:47.717 Test[57483:60b] For-in 1087754062
2014-06-11 14:37:55.492 Test[57483:60b] Enum   7775447746
```

Comment: I can confirm that running the same test on a MacBook Pro Retina 2014, `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` is actually 5X slower. That's apparently due to an autorelease pool wrapping each invocation of the block, which doesn't happen for the `for in` case.

Comment: I confirm `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` is still 4X slower on real iPhone 6 iOS9, using Xcode 7.x to build.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! I wish this answer didn't get so buried... some people just like the `enumerate` syntax because it feels FP-like and don't want to listen to performance analysis.

Comment: By the way, it’s not just due to the autorelease pool. There is a lot more stack pushing & popping with `enumerate:`

Answer (score 24):

To answer the question about performance, I made some tests using my [performance test project](https://github.com/LearnCocos2D/LearnCocos2D/tree/master/Cocos2D-Performance-Test). I wanted to know which of the three options for sending a message to all objects in an array is the fastest.

The options were:

**1) makeObjectsPerformSelector**

```
[arr makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(_stubMethod)];
```

**2) fast enumeration & regular message send**

```
for (id item in arr)
{
    [item _stubMethod];
}
```

**3) enumerateObjectsUsingBlock & regular message send**

```
[arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
 {
     [obj _stubMethod];
 }];
```

It turns out that makeObjectsPerformSelector was the slowest by far. It took twice as long as fast enumeration. And enumerateObjectsUsingBlock was the fastest, it was around 15-20% faster than fast iteration.

So if you're very concerned about the best possible performance, use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock. But keep in mind that in some cases the time it takes to enumerate a collection is dwarfed by the time it takes to run whatever code you want each object to execute.

Comment: Can you point out to your specific test? You seem to have given a wrong answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's fairly useful to use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock as an outer loop when you want to break nested loops.

e.g.

```
[array1 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj1, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
  for(id obj2 in array2) {
    for(id obj3 in array3) {
      if(condition) {
        // break ALL the loops!
        *stop = YES;
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}];
```

The alternative is using goto statements.

Comment: Or you could just return from the method just as you've done here :-D

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @bbum and @Chuck for starting comprehensive comparisons on performance. Glad to know it's trivial. I seem to have gone with:

- `for (... in ...)` - as my default goto. More intuitive to me, more programming history here than any real preference - cross language reuse, less typing for most data structures due to IDE auto complete :P.
- `enumerateObject...` - when access to object and index is needed. And when accessing non-array or dictionary structures (personal preference)
- `for (int i=idx; i<count; i++)` - for arrays, when I need to start on a non-zero index