# Objective-C Split an array into two separate arrays based on even/odd indexes

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have an array, NSMutableArray *stringArray that looks like this

```
stringArray = 

[0]String1
[1]String2
[2]String3
[3]String4
[4]String5
[5]String6
```

How would I go about splitting this array into two arrays based on even/odd indexes?

Example:

```
NSMutableArray *oddArray = ([1], [3], [5]);

NSMutableArray *evenArray = ([0], [2], [4]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are following ways you can achieve that:-

**The first and second one solution are already mentioned by the above two. Below are the implementation of the same:-**

```
//First Solution
NSArray *ar=@[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5"];
NSMutableArray *mut1=[NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *mut2=[NSMutableArray array];
[ar enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (idx%2==0)
    {
        [mut1 addObject:object];
    }
    else
    {
        [mut2 addObject:object];
    }
}];

//Second Solution
NSMutableIndexSet *idx1 = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
NSMutableIndexSet *idx2 = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
for (NSUInteger index=0; index <ar.count(); index++)
{
   if(index%2==0)
    {
        [idx1 addIndex:index];
    }
    else{
        [idx2 addIndex:index];
    }
}
NSArray *evenArr=[ar objectsAtIndexes:idx1];
NSArray *oddArr=[ar objectsAtIndexes:idx2];
NSLog(@"%@",evenArr);
NSLog(@"%@",oddArr);
```

Comment: Using "for in" loops and `indexOfObject` is terribly inefficient.

Comment: Why not use `enumerateObjects...` in the 2nd and 3rd solutions just like in the 1st?

Comment: This was the solution, and you even provided code examples, thank you so much!

Comment: solution 3 is a problematic version of solution 1. c-style for-looping does not provide mutation-guarding and is slow.

Answer (score 5):

create two mutable arrays, use `enumerateObjectsWithBlock:` on the source array and check `idx % 2` to put it into first or second array

Using the ternary operator:

```
NSArray *array = @[@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8,@9,@10,@11,@12];
NSMutableArray *even = [@[] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *odd = [@[] mutableCopy];
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSMutableArray *evenOrOdd = (idx % 2) ? even : odd;
    [evenOrOdd addObject:object];
}];
```

If you like super compact code you could use the ternary operator like

```
[((idx % 2) ? even : odd) addObject:object];
```

If you want to split the array to N arrays, you can do

```
NSArray *array = @[@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8,@9,@10,@11,@12];

NSArray *resultArrays = @[[@[] mutableCopy],
                          [@[] mutableCopy],
                          [@[] mutableCopy]];

[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [resultArrays[idx % resultArrays.count] addObject:object];
}];
```

In Objective-C Categories should come to your mind to create re-uasable code:

```
@interface NSArray (SplittingInto)
-(NSArray *)arraysBySplittingInto:(NSUInteger)N;
@end

@implementation NSArray (SplittingInto)
-(NSArray *)arraysBySplittingInto:(NSUInteger)N
{
    NSAssert(N > 0, @"N cant be less than 1");
    NSMutableArray *resultArrays = [@[] mutableCopy];
    for (NSUInteger i =0 ; i<N; ++i) {
        [resultArrays addObject:[@[] mutableCopy]];
    }

    [self enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                                [resultArrays[idx% resultArrays.count] addObject:object];
                            }];
    return resultArrays;
}
@end
```

Now you can do

```
NSArray *array = [@[@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8,@9,@10,@11,@12] arraysBySplittingInto:2];
```

`array` contains

```
(
        (
        1,
        3,
        5,
        7,
        9,
        11
    ),
        (
        2,
        4,
        6,
        8,
        10,
        12
    )
)
```

Comment: The concurrent solution would require locking on the mutable arrays.

Comment: To use concurrency, you could dispatch two operations, one for `even` and one for `odd` array and enumerate the original array twice. This may speed things up for very large arrays.

Comment: There you go, there’s my answer. ***You*** wrote a concurrent solution that is broken. Now I wrote working concurrent solution and benchmarked it. _PS: I didn’t vote you down._

Comment: `NSMutableArray` is not thread-safe, so mutating it concurrently would result in some elements missing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)

Comment: I deleted the concurrent option, as actually it is about of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 3):

Create two `NSIndexSet`s, one for the even indexes and one for the odd, then use [`objectsAtIndexes:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectsAtIndexes:) to extract the corresponding slices of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Got some time for benchmarking and it turns out that when the input array has **more than 10 million**, it’s faster to use parallel execution.

Here is the **concurrent solution** that enumerates the input array twice to prevent race conditions on the output arrays.

```
static NSArray * concurrent(NSArray *input) {
    NSUInteger capacity = input.count / 2;
    NSArray *split = @[
                       [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:capacity],
                       [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:capacity],
                       ];
    [split enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent
                            usingBlock:^(NSMutableArray *output, NSUInteger evenOdd, BOOL *stop) {
                                [input enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
                                    if (index % 2 == evenOdd) {
                                        [output addObject:object];
                                    }
                                }];
                            }];
    return split;
}
```

I consider this to be the **best serial solution**, so I used it for benchmarking:

```
static NSArray * serial(NSArray *input) {
    NSUInteger capacity = input.count / 2;
    NSMutableArray *even = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:capacity];
    NSMutableArray *odd = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:capacity];

    [input enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        NSMutableArray *output = (index % 2) ? odd : even;
        [output addObject:object];
    }];
    return @[ even, odd ];
}
```

#### Results

- 1 million elements

  - Serial: *54.081 ms*
  - Concurrent: *65.958 ms* (18% worse)
- 10 million elements

  - Serial: *525.851 ms*
  - Concurrent: *412.691 ms* (**27% better**)
- 100 million elements

  - Serial: *5244.798 ms*
  - Concurrent: *4137.939 ms* (**27% better**)

Average of 5 runs.
Input filled with `NSNumbers`.
Fastest smallest optimization `-Os`.

Comment: Your concurrent implementation is semi-concurrent, as it will use 2 threads at maximum.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Concurrent = more than one. When you are building two arrays, you can use two threads at most.

Comment: thats not true. you could use several temporary arrays and join them later. or c-arrays could be used. or … I just want to point out that with more complex algorithms a higher degree of concurrency can be achieved. But that would be out of the scope of the question and as [bbum said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6196346/106435): addressing a performance problem by moving from serial to concurrent execution usually results having two problems: performance & concurrency.