# UIButton array makes really bad performances

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, performance, uibutton

I'm trying to implement a board game, in which i need a board size of 40*26 buttons.

I implement this board as follows :

```
sizeX = 7.55;
sizeY = 7.35;
for (int i=0; i<nb_lignes; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<nb_colonnes; j++)
    {
        UIButton * test = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [test setFrame:CGRectMake((100-sizeX)+(j*(sizeX)), 50+(i*(sizeY)), (sizeX), (sizeY))];
        [test setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [test setAlpha:0.5];
        [test setTitleColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [test setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i %i", j+1, i+1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [test addTarget:self action:@selector(touchBouton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:test];
        [[LevelButton objectAtIndex:i] addObject:test];
    }
}
```

I haven't done any action that the game is really slow. For example, when i try to use the assistive touch, it goes really really slow.
Have you got an idea of how could I improve the performances of my app ?

Comment: Are nb_lignes and nb_lignes contains array count??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using for loop you can try [`-[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:)

For more details you can check [this Stack Overflow answer about using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208722/objective-c-split-an-array-into-two-separate-arrays-based-on-even-odd-indexes/27209789#27209789).

Comment: Thanks Josh for properly updating it