# Objective-C enumerateObjectsUsingBlock vs fast enumeration?

Tags: objective-c

What are the advantages and disadvantages of the following two approaches:

**[enumerate using block](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1415846-enumerateobjectsusingblock?language=objc)**

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray new];
[myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id anObject, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (anObject == someOtherObject) {
        [anObject doSomething:idx];
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
```

**[fast enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH7-SW30)**

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray new];
int idx = 0
for (id anObject in myArray) {
    if (anObject == someOtherObject) {
        [anObject doSomething:idx];
        break;
    }
    ++idx;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock vs. for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486622/when-to-use-enumerateobjectsusingblock-vs-for)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[This blog post](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-04-09-comparison-of-objective-c-enumeration-techniques.html) covers the major differences. In summary:

- Fast enumeration is available on OS X 10.5+, blocks are available on 10.6+
- For simple enumeration, fast enumeration is a bit faster than block-based enumeration
- It's easier (and more performant) to do concurrent or reverse enumeration with block-based enumeration than with fast enumeration
- When enumerating over an `NSDictionary` you can get key and value in one hit with a block-based enumerator, whereas with fast enumeration you have to use the key to retrieve the value in a separate message send.

Regarding the last point (NSDictionary enumeration), compare this:

```
for (id key in dictionary)
{
    id obj = [dictionary objectForKey: key];
    // do something with key and obj
}
```

to this:

```
[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    // do something with key and obj
}];
```

In addition, both methods protect mutable collections from mutation inside the enumeration loop. Interestingly, if you try to mutate the collection inside a block-based enumeration, you get an exception thrown by CoreFoundation's `__NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler`, suggesting that there's some common code under the hood.

```
 NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", nil];
 [myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id anObject, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
     // Attempt to mutate the array during enumeration
     [myArray addObject:@"c"];
 }];
```

Output:

```
2011-12-14 22:37:53.716 Untitled[5809:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x109614190> was mutated while being enumerated.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8cca7286 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8319ad5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8cd311dc __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 172
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8cc9efb4 __NSArrayEnumerate + 612
    4   Untitled                            0x00000001094efcea main + 250
    5   Untitled                            0x00000001094efbe4 start + 52
    6   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called throwing an exceptionRun Command: line 1:  5809 Abort trap: 6           ./"$2"
```

Comment: Leaving performance aside, which version do you guys find easier to read at first glance?

Comment: @rsanchezsaez Interesting question! I find a `for` loop over the dictionary keys more readable. Block syntax still isn't intuitive to me.

Comment: for key value, I find block more intuitive (I came from C(++) and just used block once)

Comment: maybe it's because I use python occasionally.

Comment: Im not saying this is wrong, but this post suggests that block based is more preformant. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4487012/296446

Answer (score 4):

First thoughts that come to my mind

- Blocks are available in iOS 4 and later so if you need to support older versions then you can not use the block syntax.
- They are pretty equivalent in terms of what they do apart from you can't accidentally mess up the counter in the block version.
- One other potential difference is that you can define the block elsewhere and pass in different blocks dependant on your state.

Hopefully this was just a very rough example as the code snippet is pretty poor and there are more efficient way of doing this ;)

Comment: Also, if I recall correctly, it was stated in a WWDC 2010 video that block enumeration is even more performant than fast enumeration.

Comment: That's the problem with the videos you know there is good stuff in there but good luck finding it again at a later date. I looked at the docs for [Enumeration: Traversing a Collection’s Elements](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html) and there was no stand out mention of a performance increase :S

Comment: Actually, I just found it. It's the "What's New in Foundation for iOS 4" video from 2010.

Comment: Nice work it really is hard to track stuff down even if you know what video it is in.