# Iterate over NSTableview or NSArrayController to get data

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I have an NSTableview which s bound to a NSArrayController.  The Table/Arraycontroller contains Core Data "Person" entities. The people are added to the NSTableview by the GUI's user.

Let's say a person entity looks like

```
NSString* Name;
int Age;
NSString* HairColor;
```

Now I want to iterate over what is stored in the array controller to perform some operation in it.  The actual operation I want to do isn't important I don't really want to get bogged down in what I am trying to do with the information.   It's just iterating over everything held in the NSArraycontroller which is confusing me.  I come from a C++ and C# background and am new to Cocoa.  Let's say I want to build a NSMutableArray that contains each person from nsarraycontroller 1 year in the future.

So I would want to do something like

```
NSMutableArray* mutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

foreach(PersonEntity p in myNsArrayController)  // foreach doesn't exist in obj-c
{

  Person* new_person = [[Person alloc] init];
  [new_person setName:p.name];
  [new_person setHairColor:p.HairColor];
  [new_person setAge:(p.age + 1)];
  [mutArray addObject:new_person];

}
```

I believe the only thing holding me back from doing something like the code above is that foreach does not exist in Obj-c.  I just don't see how to iterate over the nsarraycontroller.

Note:  This is for OSX so I have garbage collection turned on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [fast enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac///documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html).

For your example, something like

```
for (PersonEntity *p in myNsArrayController.arrangedObjects)
{
    // Rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also enumerate using blocks. For example:

```
[myNsArrayController enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
 {
       PersonEntity *p = object;
       // Rest of your code
 }];
```

There's pro's and cons to both approaches. These are discussed in depth in the answer to this question:

[Objective-C enumerateUsingBlock vs fast enumeration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509662/objective-c-enumerateusingblock-vs-fast-enumeration)

You can find a great tutorial on blocks in Apple's WWDC 2010 videos. In that they say that at Apple they use blocks "all the time".