# iOS are fast enumeration collection statement executed multiple times?

Tags: ios, performance, for-loop, foreach, fast-enumeration

Both variants are exactly the same right?

**Variant 1:**

```
for(id<MyAwesomeProtocol> obj in [self.instances copy]) {
    ...
}
```

**Variant 2:**

```
NSArray *instancesCopy = [self.instances copy];
for(id<MyAwesomeProtocol> obj in instancesCopy) {
    ...
}
```

Will the copy method `[self.instances copy]` in variant 1 called multiple times for each loop?

It will only be executed once at the beginning of the loop right? So this makes code like variant 2 pretty unnecessary? Am I right?

I think I got confused because the condition statement in normal for-loop **will** be executed on each loop. Instead of writing:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [self.instances count]; i++) {

}
```

It might be better (in some cases) to cache the count once for performance reasons:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0, count = [self.instances count]; i < count; i++) {

}
```

Does this still hold true for LLVM 6.0 (Xcode 6.0, iOS 8.0)? Or will such code optimized by the compiler?

PS: I'm not really sure how to phrase my stupid question title ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this an inefficient way of using fast enumeration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281461/is-this-an-inefficient-way-of-using-fast-enumeration)

Comment: Such cases should be optimized by the compiler, not by the programmer.

Comment: @rintaro thx for point me to the right question. correct keywords didn't really come in mind when i tried to search for it ;)