# fast enumeration versus enumerateObjectsUsingBlock

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, fast-enumeration

Consider:

```
- (void) testing {
    NSMutableArray * numbers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10000000] ;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000000 ; ++i) {
        [numbers addObject:@(i)] ;
    }

    NSInteger (^sum)(NSInteger, NSInteger) = ^(NSInteger running, NSInteger n) {
        return running + n ;
    } ;

    double start = ::CACurrentMediaTime() ;
    __block NSInteger running = 0 ;
    for (NSNumber * n in numbers) {
        running = sum(running, [n integerValue]) ;
    }
    running = 0 ;
    double end1 = ::CACurrentMediaTime() ;
    [numbers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber * n, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        running = sum(running, [n integerValue]) ;
    }] ;
    double end2 = ::CACurrentMediaTime() ;

    ::NSLog(@"fastEnum: %0.3f, enumUsingBlock: %0.3f", end1-start, end2-end1) ;
}
```

This outputs:

```
2013-08-05 00:38:34.852 WC[48299:a0b] fastEnum: 0.341, enumUsingBlock: 1.358
```

This says that `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` is 4x slower or so than regular iteration.

When does one use one or the other? 
What is the "added value" that `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` provides that justifies its cost?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock vs. for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486622/when-to-use-enumerateobjectsusingblock-vs-for)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mattt Thompson wrote a [great post on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/enumerators/) about the many ways to iterate with Objective-C.

The added value that `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` provides is giving the index of the object and `NSEnumerationOptions`:

```
enum {
   NSEnumerationConcurrent = (1UL << 0),
   NSEnumerationReverse = (1UL << 1),
};
typedef NSUInteger NSEnumerationOptions;
```

Quoting Mattt:

> Unless you actually need the numerical index while iterating, it's almost always faster to use a for/in NSFastEnumeration loop instead.
>
> (...)
>
> Again, fast enumeration is almost certain to be much faster than block enumeration, but these options may be useful if you're resigned to using blocks.