# Search in a big NSMutableArray of NSDictionary

Tags: ios, sqlite, search, nsmutablearray

I need to search in a big NSMutableArray of NSDictionary with about 50.000 record. I try with:

```
for (NSDictionary *aProduct in self.arrProduct) {
    if ([[aProduct objectForKey:@"Name"]rangeOfString:@"search string" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
        //got it
    }
}
```

but with 50.000 object, this function had performance very bad. 
I do not want to use Sqlite to search.
Any idea?

tks,

Comment: is "self.arrProduct" local array?

Comment: Maybe a `NSPredicate`?

Comment: Why would you have such a big array on a mobile device? Why not SQLite / Core Data?

Comment: Indeed; it must be eating RAM as well, not to mention time taken to populate the array of dictionaries.

Comment: please some where put a sample data. I think @" trojanfoe" said right. some where object eating RAM. So, far i know local array searching supposed to be super fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: instead of fast enumeration.

Take a look at [this](http://nshipster.com/enumerators/) for more details.

Also: [enumurateObjectsUsingBlock Vs for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486622/when-to-use-enumerateobjectsusingblock-vs-for)

Comment: It will still be slow.

Comment: 50k records is a lot, but enumerateObjectsUsingBlocks with still be faster or as fast. To quote the 2nd link:
"enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: will be as fast or faster than fast enumeration (for(... in ...) uses the NSFastEnumeration support to implement enumeration). Fast enumeration requires translation from an internal representation to the representation for fast enumeration. There is overhead therein. "

Comment: I'm not sure how much faster it will be in your case, but you can compare them and let us know the results

Comment: It isn't the enumeration that will be slow. It will be the `rangeOfString`. Even with sql this is an expensive search.

Comment: The array needs to be thrown away in favour of a binary tree or somesuch.

Comment: i changed to Sqlite because my custom have an other store with 200k product :(

Answer (score 0):

If each data has an unique key, and what you want is searching with an unique key, then you can use `Hash table`.

Or, the search key is a number, and you need `range search`, ex `key > 5 && key < 10`. Then I think `ordered binary tree` will be helpful. The implementation of binary tree might be found in the `GitHub`, I supports to someone had done it already.

---

As for me, I prefer to use `SQLite` to solve this kind problem. Adding an index to the search key will faster the search performance. I don't like to store huge data in the main memory.

Comment: yes, i changed to SQLite because i found an other store with 200k products. and can not use NSUserDefault to cache.

Comment: If you need cache, maybe [TMCache](https://github.com/tumblr/TMCache) can help you. Generally, `Database system` will implement some cache mechanism to increase performance. I use `SQLite cache` as keywords and google gives many posts.

Answer (score 0):

finally, i use CoreData. Array can not run smooth with big size data.